# How to take picture from Live face detection using Firebase_Camera_ml_vision

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit, image-capture, google-mlkit

I using flutter_camera_ml_vision 2.2.5 and there face detection example from their repository.
Please can someone tell me how to take picture from live detection?

Here is the link to the code:- https://github.com/rushio-consulting/flutter_camera_ml_vision/blob/master/example/lib/main_face.dart

Comment: I have managed to detect live face with this library. But my app crashes if I try to capture image. Is there any way to use this library without crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flutter_camera_ml_vision is not what firebase team provides officially. 
You may want to try the `firebase_ml_vision` plugin, which explains how to do it. 
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision